# Problem with my ToDoList , findAndRemoveById dont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

im doing my course and now making a ToDoList and upgrading it with mongoose but the problem is that in this video everything work fine but for me its showing ,,Argument passed in must be a single String ...,, when trying to use delete by checkbox        `enter code here`

```
//jshint esversion:6

    enter code here

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

//mongoose database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB", {useFindAndModify: false,useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true});

const itemsSchema = {
  name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item" , itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Welcome to Your ToDoList!"
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Hit + to add new item."
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "<- Hit this to delete item."
});

const defaultItems = [item1 , item2 , item3];


app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  Item.find(function(err , items){
    //add new items to our collection
    if(items.length === 0){
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems , function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          console.log("Added new items to DB.");
        }
      });
      res.redirect("/");
    }else{

      mongoose.connection.close();
   res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: items});

    }
  });

});
/////
/// Adding new item to our list
app.post("/", function(req, res){

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;

  const newItem = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });
newItem.save();

res.redirect("/");
});

//deleting item by checkbox
app.post("/delete" , function(req,res){
const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}else{
  console.log("Successfully deleted item.");
}
});
res.redirect("/");
});


/////
app.get("/work", function(req,res){
  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work List", newListItems: workItems});
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});

and here where this checkbox is

  <div class="box">
  <%  newListItems.forEach(function(item){%>

    <form action="/delete" method="post">
    <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()">
    <p> <%= item.name %> </p>
    </div>
    </form>
  <%  }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is where is the checkbox.**

```
 <div class="box">
      <%  newListItems.forEach(function(item){%>
    
        <form action="/delete" method="post">
        <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <p> <%= item.name %> </p>
        </div>
        </form>
      <%  }); %>
```

**You should include the value in the input so the code should look like this:**

```
<div class="box">
  <%  newListItems.forEach(function(item){%>

    <form action="/delete" method="post">
    <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item._id %>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
    <p> <%= item.name %> </p>
    </div>
    </form>
  <%  }); %>
```